# WooCommerce wrong language

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I installed WooCommerce into my Wordpress site which is using Bridge theme, but I am not able to change the language. It's always displayed in english but I need to change it to german. While looking at the folder structure inside FTP access I can only see files which contain the correct language code (de_AT) but still all default WooCommerce pages are shown in english.

`/wp-content/languages -> correct language files de_AT`

`/wp-content/languages/plugins/ -> woocommerce-payments-de_AT.json`

Wordpress language and profile language is also set to german.
Does anyone know what to do?

Help very appreciated, thanks!